# Background image and IE issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a large dimension image that i have to scaled down through css. But in IE image getting distorted. It seems background-size property is buggy in IE.

CSS:

```
.img{
      height: 33px;
    width: 65px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
  background-image:url("http://www.answerplot.com/ap/media/images/croplan_logo.gif");
}
```

I already tried `background-size:100%/cover/contain`.
Working example:http://codepen.io/Mishra-Praveen/pen/revjGJ

[image]

I am fed up with this issue tried many css properties but didn't help. 
Not getting any solution.

Comment: What *version* of IE are you referring to?

Comment: verifying in IE edge

Comment: I don't think this is a background-size issue, but rather an IE/Edge interpolation issue.  I had some success improving things with a transform rotation but it is not a real solution.  Here is a link to a request to improve interpolation in IE/Edge https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e800cbaf-a539-43ba-b5f9-1d29fe709ddc/the-awful-internet-explorer-image-renderengine?forum=ieitprocurrentver  Also note the canvas based solution in the comments.